# XAMPP on Debian7 starting Apache fails

Tags: apache, xampp, debian

I install [xampp](/questions/tagged/xampp) on my debian 7,and when I try to start it, I have gotten  an error message `start apache fail`, I use the ps -A to show if I had run another web service ,but I failed.
How to solve this issue?

```
/opt/lampp/lampp start
```

> Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.2-2...
>
> XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
>
> XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
>
> XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
>
> XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

when debian7 start,it will start apache2.
so you should stop it first,than try to start lampp.

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
/opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

that maybe work.try it.

Comment: To anyone looking to make this permanent:
sudo update-rc.d -f apache2 remove

Answer (score 2):

Another Way .Just press **Ctrl+Alt+T** on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

1. **`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop`**
2. **`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`**
3. **`sudo /etc/init.d/proftpd stop`**
4. **`sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`**

Answer (score 1):

1.Open the file /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf
Search the "Listen 80" and change it to some other port (e.g. Listen 2145) (Line No. 40)
2. Open the file /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
Search the "Listen 443" and change it to some other port (e.g. Listen 16443) (Line No. 39)
3. Open the file /opt/lampp/lampp
   Search for the port "testport 80" and replace it to "testport 2145".
 4.Also change the "testport 443" to "testport 16443". (Happens to be the 
 Line No. 197, 214)
5.Now go and run /opt/lampp/lampp start. (It should work now).

Comment: Nowhere does the user complain about port issues, not related.

Answer (score 0):

First you should stop your apache server:

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop`

Then stop mysql:

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`

`sudo /etc/init.d/proftpd stop`

At last restart your lampp server:

`sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart`

This also works on UBUNTU 14.04.