# PhP local host redirecting to /var/www/html/index.php

Tags: php, html, xampp, lampp

I am using Ubuntu machine. I am running lampp server for php files.

I have all my PHP files in `my_folder` where I have all my codes in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/my_folder` including index file in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/my_folder/index.php`.

I wanted to check my codes by running `http://localhost/index.php` in Chrome browser, but for some reason it keeps directing me to `/var/www/html/html.index` file. Can someone please help me resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to you apache config.

```
DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_folder
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_folder>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks, it now redirects to the desired path only generating the actual code in the browser. It doesn't execute the codes. What could be the reason?

Comment: Check you php by put the info.php in your rootpath, then access it.

Comment: Thanks. This was the issue and the answer here fixed it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533439/xampp-on-debian7-starting-apache-fails

Answer (score 0):

Adittionally, If MySQL doesn't start:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/proftpd stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```