# Stopping old XAMPP background processes

Tags: php, linux, server, terminal, xampp

I reinstalled an old XAMPP program on my PC because an error occurred on the old one. Unfortunately, I forgot to stop the three servers before uninstalling. Now I always get an error

> XAMPP: Stopping Apache ... not running.   XAMPP: Stopping MySQL ...
> ok. XAMPP: Stopping ProFTPD ... not running.

If I want to start the three new servers of the new XAMPP program. I now suspect that the old processes did not end after uninstalling the old program. I also ended my Apache2 server, which also runs on my PC. I have already looked into the system monitoring but found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must go to the Terminal and type

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

More Information you can find here: [XAMPP on Debian7 starting Apache fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533439/xampp-on-debian7-starting-apache-fails)